# How to popToRootViewController from within a modal view?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a typical UITableViewController set of views.  On all views is a button, which brings up a model view.  On that Settings view is a button.  I would like that button to dismiss the modal view *and* implement popToRootViewController on the UITableViewController's navigationController.

Dismissing the modal view is easy:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

and that works fine.  I've tried this to pop the main UITableViewController:

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

and nothing happens.

I can probably implement a delegate to make this happen but there are quite a few view controllers with the same Settings button (with more to come) so a preference to find a solution that doesn't require additional code in each view controller.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution like this, so I've implemented a protocol/delegate which works fine. Just:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

in the delegate call.

Answer (score 7):

check out the answer by rdelmal (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311935/1395563), this worked like a charm for me. I use this code in an action in the modal view.

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController  popToRootViewController:NO];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow] rootViewController] popToRootViewController:YES];
```

Comment: That's missing the navigationController (so won't compile) but even with that added as [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow rootViewController] navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; it compiles but does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

add a method in your appdelegate file

```
-(void)GotoRoot{
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

Now call it in your classs on ur logout button

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[(TestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) GotoRoot];
```

please revert its result;

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
[[self parentViewController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]
```