# Pop to root view controller from modal

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to pop to the root view controller using the following code:

```
self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

This usually works, but I get an error when trying to use this code when the current view is a modal. How do I go about popping back to the root view controller in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can check that current controller is presented, if it is presented then dismiss it and the go to the `rootViewController` other wise go directly the `rootViewController`

```
if self.presentingViewController != nil {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { 
       self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    })
}
else {
    self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Looks like the `self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`  in the completion handler may not be correct? Shouldn't you be using the `presentingViewController`'s navigation controller to pop to root?

Answer (score 16):

## Result:

[image]

## Code

Let's say that your Modal View has the below ViewController associated.

Basically first to hide your View that is shown as a **Modal**, you use `dismiss(animated: Bool)` method from your ViewController instance.

And for the Views presented as **Pushed**, you could use from your navigationController property these methods for instance: `popToRootViewController(animated: Bool)`, `popViewController(animated:Bool)`

```
class ModalViewController: UIViewController {
  
  @IBAction func backButtonTouched(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let navigationController = self.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController
    
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
      let _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have presented a ViewController, so you need to dismiss it.

To dismiss a ViewController in swift, use this:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the animations to happen, i.e. you want user to see the root view controller after the modal view is dismissed:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Reference from: [Completion block for popViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904410/completion-block-for-popviewcontroller)

The above will work for popping a single view controller. If you need to pop multiple, `popToRootViewController` will not work (there is an unbalanced call due to animations).

In that case, use the following (manual) method to remove them:

```
guard let navigationController = self.navigationController else { return }
var navigationViewControllers = navigationController.viewControllers
navigationViewControllers.removeLast(navigationViewControllers.count - 1)
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = navigationViewControllers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

***Objective-C:***

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Check answer here for reference:

[ios: how to dismiss a modal view controller and then pop a pushed view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311305/ios-how-to-dismiss-a-modal-view-controller-and-then-pop-a-pushed-view-controlle/16311935#16311935)

Answer (score 0):

How about use Notification?

your modal just post Notification

and your NavigationController receive then, pop to rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

I created a project with a custom navigation bar so that the root back button can be in the navigation bar. The green arrow goes back one View, while the blue x will pop back to the root view which is my case is the ContentView.

[image]

Here are my example views to show how it works.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var globalObj: GlobalClass
    var body: some View {
        CustomNavView{
            VStack{
                RootCustomNavLink(destination: FirstView()
                .customNavigationTitle("Custom View").customNavigationBarReturnButtonHidden(true), label: {
                        Text("Navigate View One").buttonStyleBlue()
                    })
                }.customNavigationTitle("Home")
                    .customNavigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .customNavigationBarReturnButtonHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, View One!")
        CustomNavLink(destination: LastView()
        .customNavigationTitle("Last View").customNavigationSubtitle("subtitle"), label: {
            Text("Go to Last View").buttonStyleGreen()
        })
    }
}

struct LastView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Last View")
    }
}
```

Here is my GitHub repo that has the structs that I made to build this custom navigation view.

https://github.com/MicahKimel/CustomNavigationSwiftUI