# Pop to rootviewcontroler containing presented navigation as well

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

My app architecture is :

- RootNavigationController
- -(rootVC)> HomeVC
- -(pushed)> SecondVC
- -(presented)> SecondNavigationController
- -(rootVC)> ThirdVC
- -(pushed)> FourthVC.

Now there is an option of returning to HomeVC on FourthVC.

What I have tried:

1)

```
  APPDELEGATE.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.HomeNavigationViewController()
```

Problem :
This way all VCs added on RootNavigationController are not deinitilized and **memory leaked**.

2)

```
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  (self.navigationController?.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.removeAll()
 APPDELEGATE.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.HomeNavigationViewController()
```

This way its **working fine** but what I need to know is there any better way of doing it.

Comment: Try this one: `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: see this approach : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39831374/3901620

Comment: try this also let navigationController = self.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController

    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
      let _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }

Comment: ok guys let me test it.

Comment: @Laffen your method suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: @KKRocks your suggestion equals to dismiss and it only removes presented VCs.

Comment: it is check first if present then dismiss it and then pop back to root .

Comment: yep I tried that