# Clear Navigation stack of viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, tabbarcontroller

> I have a tabBarController with four tabs. From each tab, I can navigate through a series of view controllers. And at the last view controller, I have a 'Done' button, clicking on which I have to be redirected to my initial tabBarController.  The code I am using currently to do this is as follows (on button click).

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
if let tabViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as? UITabBarController {
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(tabViewController, animated: false)
}
```

But I feel this is not correct way since the navigation stack keeps on adding. Instead I would like to clear the navigation stack and show the first tabBarController in the stack. How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pop to root view controller from modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830955/pop-to-root-view-controller-from-modal)

Comment: Use the popToRootViewController(animated:) method on your navigationController. This makes sure that all the viewcontrollers in the array of view controllers are popped. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller

Answer (score 6):

make your first viewController your root view controller then on button click

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: I also have splash screen as First viewController, if user go through login process then root viewcontroller will be splash view controller and after login tabbar controller will be display.

Comment: you can change your root view controller after login

Answer (score 2):

I think setting root controller will solve your problem.

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
   let tabVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabViewController())
   window.rootViewController = tabVC
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to set root view controller as you have put the code and later pop to this root view controller?

Comment: Not sure about this, but popToRootViewController clear the stack. setting root controller also shoulf clear stack

Answer (score 0):

Use available method >>

func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]?

> > This method  clears the stack and places you at the root view controller
> >     please read the documentation for detail

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller?changes=_4

Comment: When you reach the root view controller you find yourself at one of the tabs of your tab bar controller. Then you can switch tabs.