# Swift dismiss current Viewcontroller after presenting new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to create multiple `present ViewController`. Here, presenting new ViewController after I need to dismiss previous ViewController.

`ViewController A (RootViewController)` next button click to presenting `ViewController B` then View Controller B next button click to present `ViewController C`. Now, If I close ViewController C need to show `ViewController A`.

[image: example]

Comment: Might I suggest you take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULd2v4mHyQ4

Comment: @Craz1k0ek there is nothing clear idea also I am looking for present model view controller

Comment: I did not understand your question. When you dismiss C, you want to show A ? Or you want to dismiss the current VC before presenting next VC ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri when I dismiss C, I need to show A.

Comment: `self.presentingViewController?. presentingViewController?.dismiss...`

Comment: Better to use a navigation controller, and push & pop view controllers from it, instead of directly displaying and dismissing.

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520899/single-function-to-dismiss-all-open-view-controllers

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry My design present ViewController. I would like to know how to do that

Comment: you need to have a reference to your viewController B, and you can only show A by dismissing both B and C. In your C controller, dismiss both C and B or just the dismiss the initial Vc.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri. Yes exactly I am trying to get. Please post some code

Comment: please refer the link posted by Anbu.Kartik

Comment: @TejaNandamuri. I am using this UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil). its working fine for first time but If I close Viewcontroller A. I am showing tabbarviewcontroller again tab bar item one click to show this VC A to B and C, now if I close it. it is showing slightly Tabbar controller first time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pop to root view controller from modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830955/pop-to-root-view-controller-from-modal)

Comment: @zb1995. first read my question and then make it duplicate. I am asking about present viewcontroller. You marked with navigation controller. Please mark it genuine don't do for credits. also why you gave downvoted for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can proceed,

```
class VCA: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func onTapNextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCB") as? VCB {
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Since `VCC` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, you need to present `UINavigationController` instead of `VCC`.

For this subclass `UINavigationController` and set it as `class` of `UINavigationController` in the `storyboard`.

```
class VCB: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func onTapNextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavVC") {
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            self.presentingViewController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

class NavVC: UINavigationController {}

class VCC: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func onTapCloseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have navigation controller in VC-C. How to add it?

Comment: You mean VC-C is the rootViewController of navigationController?

Comment: Yes, I embed with navigation controller.

Comment: Updated the answer for that.